# Drupal Gardens Default Front page text

Tags: drupal, frontpage

How I can remove this text(Welcome to islanders No front page content has been created yet. Add new content) which is auto generated by the drupal garden on home or front page of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Drupal's standard behaviour when there's no front page content. Just do this to change it:

1. Create some new content (e.g. at `node/add/page`) that you would like to be the front page.
2. Go to `admin/config/system/site-information` and set the **Default front page** to the path of the new content/node.